# I still don't get it why I'm getting an error:

Tags: c#

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string[] entries = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Keywords.txt");
            foreach (string entry in entries)
            {
                string[] values = entry.Split(',');
                LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
                for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
                    LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Add(values[i]);
            }
            using (var w = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Keywords.txt"))
            {
                crawlLocaly1 = new CrawlLocaly();
                crawlLocaly1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                DialogResult dr = crawlLocaly1.ShowDialog(this);
                if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(mainUrl))
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Clear();
                        //probably you could skip this part and create new List everytime
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl] = new List<string>();
                        LocalyKeyWords[mainUrl].Add(crawlLocaly1.getText());
                    }
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in LocalyKeyWords)
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(kvp.Key + "," + string.Join(",", kvp.Value));
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
```

The error is on the line:

```
LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
```

The error is: `KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary`

LocalyKeyWords is a List:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> LocalyKeyWords = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

And the file `Keywords.txt` is not empty now :

```
http://www.cnet.com,changing for test
http://www.wlala.co.co,adding
```

And yet when reading the file I'm getting the exception. 
I see that on the error line that `LocalyKeyWords` is empty 0 but values contain two indexes :

```
[0] http://www.cnet.com and [1] changing for test
```

Index 0 is the url and index 1 is the url key!

I tried to add before this line and change the code there a bit to:

```
if (LocalyKeyWords.Count == 0)
   {                         
    LocalyKeyWords[values[0]] = new List<string>();
   }
   else
   {
    LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
   }
```

But it didn't work and it didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting the error on the line.
How can I fix it?

The List is built this way: url,key for exmaple: http://www.google.com","google
also the text file format is like that:

```
http://www.cnet.com,changing for test
http://www.wlala.co.co,adding
```

changing for test is the key of http://www.cnet.com
and addin is the key for http://www.wlala.co.co

So I want to do two things when reading back the url,key from the text file:

1. To add the url and its belonging key to a `ListBox` so I did it in the constructor. I want to do it in the button click event each time the user change a key for a url or add a new url and its key so the user will see in real time the changes in ListBox. In the constructor I'm adding the url and keys and show it in the ListBox like this:

   sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\Keywords.txt");
                   while (null != (line = sr.ReadLine()))
                   {

   ```
                   index = line.IndexOf(",");
                   key_of_each_line = line.Substring(0, index);
                   value_of_each_key = line.Substring(index + 1);
                   listBox1.Items.Add("Url: " + key_of_each_line + " --- " + "Key: " + value_of_each_key );
               }
               sr.Close();
   ```

sr is a `StreamReader`.
And it's working good in the constructor. The same format in the constructor. I want to show it in real time in the button click event when the user add new/change a key/s or url/s

1. To fix the reading part as it is now in the button click event with exception error.

---

The new reading part code:

```
if (File.Exists(@"d:\Keywords.txt"))
            {
                string[] entries = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Keywords.txt");
                foreach (string entry in entries)
                {
                    string[] values = entry.Split(',');
                    if (LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(values[0]))
                        LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
                    else
                        LocalyKeyWords[values[0]] = new List<string>();
                    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
                        LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Add(values[i]);
                }
            }
```

Added also a check if the file exist in case the user deleted it. But if the file exist I don't want that each time the user click the button it will create a new empty text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does doing this sort out the issue:

```
foreach (string entry in entries)
{
    string[] values = entry.Split(',');
    LocalyKeyWords[values.First()] = values.Skip(1).ToList();
}
```

Alternatively, if you can reassign `LocalyKeyWords` you could do this:

```
var LocalyKeyWords =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(@"D:\Keywords.txt")
        .Select(entry =>
        {
            var values = entry.Split(',');
            return new
            {
                key = values.First(),
                values = values.Skip(1).ToList(),
            };
        })
        .ToDictionary(kv => kv.key, kv => kv.values);
```

The latter method is preferable as it is fully rebuilding the dictionary and therefore there is no way that there could be existing keys.

Comment: Enigmativity it didnt slove the problem that when i close the program run it again and click the button to add/change url/key so its creating a new text file instead change/add it to the existing text file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the key in your dictionary. Try checking whether the key is present in the dictionary and clear it then. Besides if the key is not in the dictionary you don't need to clear it. Then you'll have to add the key to the dictionary.:

```
if(LocalyKeyWords.ContainsKey(values[0]))
    LocalyKeyWords[values[0]].Clear();
else
    LocalyKeyWords[values[0]] = new List<string>();
```

Try reading [Dictionary.Item Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2.aspx), where it's said:

> If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a
>   KeyNotFoundException, and a set operation creates a new element with
>   the specified key.

Comment: Konstantin i tried your code here see in my question i updated with an upadted code of the reading file part. But now each time i click the button its creating a new empty text file and i dont want it to be like that i want the old text file to be kept and not to create a new one each time i click the button.

Comment: @DanielLip Consider using `new StreamWriter("Your file path",true)` constructor

Comment: @DanielLip http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx

Comment: Konstantin i know about the ,true but doing this will keep adding url/keys in a new line and the idea is that in the writing area code that if i change to a new url and put a key for it it will add to the List the new url with its key and if i change the url back to old url that is already in the List and change to this url its old key to a new one so it will replace the new key with the new one. Setting the StreamWriter to ,true make it not ot happen but just adding even old url and old key as a new line.

Comment: @DanielLip Don't you think that this should be a separate question?